# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$ruta' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\funcion.php on line 5

Tags: php, xml, xampp

> Soy nuevo en este foro y tambien soy nuevo aprendiendo php, mi problema es que cuando trato de correrlo en mi navegador me aparece este error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$ruta' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\funcion.php on line 5

*conexion.php*

```
$conexmysql = new conexmysql("localhost", "root", "", "seasons");

if ($conexmysql->connection_errno) {
    die("Fallo la conexión");
} 
else {
}
```

*funcion.php*

```
require "conexion.php";

$ruta = simplexml_load_file("/XAMPP/htdocs/places.xml");
$count = 0;

foreach ($ruta->place_id as $places) {
    $insert = "INSERT INTO `places`(`place_id`, `name`, `cre_id`, `location_x`, `location_y`) VALUES ('$places->place_id', '$places->name', '$places->cre_id')";



    if($cn->query($insert) === TRUE) {
        echo "Se inserto la información correctamente <br> <br>";
    }
    else {
        echo "Hubo un error al insertar en la tabla: ". $cn->error . " <br> <br>";
    }

    $count++;
}
echo "</br>";
echo "____________________________________________</br>";
echo "Total de regristros guardados: $count </br>";
echo "____________________________________________</br>";

$conexmysql->close();
```

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código de `conexion.php`, me parece que el error puede estar ahí, seguramente omitiste un `;`

Comment: ya lo he agregado

Comment: Si no vas a publicar tu código completo, revisa que cada línea termine con punto y coma.

Comment: Es todo el codigo de conexión y de funcion no hay más.

Comment: por qué no estás guardando datos en location_x y location_y?